# Get the number or frequency of accesses to each member variable of a structure

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

This is a C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct demo1 {
    long long A;
    long long B;

};
struct demo2 {
    long long C;
    long long D;
    float E;
};

int main(){
    struct demo1 d1;
    struct demo2 d2;
    d1.A = 1;
    d2.C = 2;
    d2.D = d1.A + d2.C;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get the number or frequency of accesses to each member variable of a structure in my code via LLVM IR, for example in this form: "`name: demo1 elements: A-2,B-0; name: demo2 elements: C-2,D-1,E-0`"
I added source code debugging information using the -O0 -g command when generating the intermediate file, in part as follows：

```
!11 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "main", scope: !3, file: !3, line: 16, type: !12, 
scopeLine: 16, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition, unit: !2, retainedNodes: !4)
!12 = !DISubroutineType(types: !13)
!13 = !{!6}
!14 = !DILocalVariable(name: "d1", scope: !11, file: !3, line: 17, type: !15)
!15 = distinct !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, name: "demo1", file: !3, line: 3,size: 128, elements: !16)
!16 = !{!17, !19}
!17 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "A", scope: !15, file: !3, line: 4, baseType: !18, size: 64)
!18 = !DIBasicType(name: "long long int", size: 64, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
!19 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "B", scope: !15, file: !3, line: 5, baseType: !18, size: 64, offset: 64)
!20 = !DILocation(line: 17, column: 18, scope: !11)
!21 = !DILocalVariable(name: "d2", scope: !11, file: !3, line: 18, type: !22)
!22 = distinct !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, name: "demo2", file: !3, line: 8, size: 192, elements: !23)
!23 = !{!24, !25, !26}
!24 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "C", scope: !22, file: !3, line: 9, baseType: !18, size: 64)
!25 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "D", scope: !22, file: !3, line: 10, baseType: !18, size: 64, offset: 64)
!26 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "E", scope: !22, file: !3, line: 11, baseType: !27, size: 32, offset: 128)
!27 = !DIBasicType(name: "float", size: 32, encoding: DW_ATE_float)
!28 = !DILocation(line: 18, column: 18, scope: !11)
!29 = !DILocation(line: 19, column: 5, scope: !11)
!30 = !DILocation(line: 19, column: 7, scope: !11)
!31 = !DILocation(line: 20, column: 5, scope: !11)
!32 = !DILocation(line: 20, column: 7, scope: !11)
!33 = !DILocation(line: 21, column: 12, scope: !11)
!34 = !DILocation(line: 21, column: 19, scope: !11)
!35 = !DILocation(line: 21, column: 14, scope: !11)
!36 = !DILocation(line: 21, column: 5, scope: !11)
!37 = !DILocation(line: 21, column: 7, scope: !11)
!38 = !DILocation(line: 22, column: 2, scope: !11)
```

How do I extract this information?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is find the GEPs that correspond to the field based on the field's indexes and your compiler; these may be either [getelementptr instructions](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html) or [GEP constant expressions](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#a32947e091cb9ab02766ea84e58c6d996) if the access is to a global variable, so you need something like `isa\<CastInst\>(…) || (isa\<ConstantExpr\>(…) && …->getOpcode()==…)`. I assume you're dealing with typesafe language, because I really don't want to go into bitcast pointers (`CastInst::getOpcode() == BitCast`, or the equivanelt for `ConstantExpr`) and their potential for generating additional ways to access each field.

Once you have those, the next part is simple: loop over their [users()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a793bafeae1be7dfa4a7ad9661ed2c404), check whether each user `isa\<LoadInst\>`, `StoreInst`, `CmpXchgInst`, and (the simple part ends here) treat each as appropriate.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer, I'll go study the relevant official documents, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think the official documentation will help you much with this particular qustion; try compiling a function that makes a struct and accesses a few fields, then looking at this answer together with that function's IR and in particular how the GEPs relate to the load/store instructions.

Comment: Does this C code I gave above meet the requirements?

Comment: Yes, that should do. And the IR for main(), of course.